# DOS Batch file - Need help to reading a text file to create a folder then two sub folders in the that folder

Tags: batch-file, directory, dos, subdirectory

```
for /F "tokens=*" %* in (C:\Test.txt) do (md "C:\TEMP\%*" || cd "C:\TEMP\%*" || md "Computer" || md "Email")
```

With this command I can create the one folder per name in test.txt but it won't let me create the subfolders.

Ideally it would create folder *Smith* then every folder would get two identical subfolders  *Car* and *House*.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very impressive usage of batch script. :-) It has been long since I last saw someone writing .bat script. Would you try:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %x in (C:\Test.txt) do mkdir c:\temp\%x\Computer c:\temp\%x\Email
```

- mkdir accepts multiple directory names.
- you must do "cd .." if you do "cd C:\temp" at first. but cd is not necessary at all.

Comment: @shr . can you tell me how i can read prefix names from text file and change the files names located in a folder using those prefixes ? text file looks like this mango,A.jpg(one below each other) and i want to change A.jpg to mango_A.jpg and ... could you show me how this can be done?Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1788736 I'm not very good at batch scripting. Though just read a [Microsoft Document](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true) and got an idea like `for /f "delims=*" %l in (test.txt) do for /f "delims=, tokens=1,2" %a in ("%l") do echo rename %b %a_%b`. Try and check the output makes what you want, and then remove `echo` part and run again.